# Using python to change contrast of an image but its too SLOW

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

i am trying to implement changing contrast in python from scratch. But its too slow, takes up around 30 seconds to process a single image. Too many for loops can be issue for this but can anyone please suggest me the right way of how to optimize. Sorry if its a naive question. But really need some new perspective on how to deal with this. Just incase someone is curious about factor value it ranges like this -0.5,0,0.5,2.

```
def ChangeContrast(self,factor):

        img= self.img
        self.height,self.width = img.shape[:2]
        for ch in range(self.channels):
            for i in range(self.height):
                for j in range(self.width):
                            img[i][j][ch]= np.clip(factor * (img[i,j][ch] - 128)+ 128,0,255)

                    
        return img
```

Thanks!!

Comment: If you're using numpy anyway, then you could be using numpy array operations, rather than nested loops, to change the pixels, which should be orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

Python is an inherently slow language, so every time you hand a line to the Python interpreter you are taking a hit in performance.

Numpy is one way to get around this because numpy allows you to do operations on entire arrays at once.

It's actually very easy to convert your nested for loops to:

```
np.clip(factor*(img - 128)+128,0,255)
```

From experience, when working with images, opencv will give you even better performance then numpy. But since you say you are implementing from scratch I'm guessing you aren't looking for that.

EDIT:

In your for loops you were using item assignments into a numpy array with an integer datatype so numpy was automatically casting the result to an integer. But in my version numpy created a new array and decided it should be float since it was created by multiplying a floating point number (factor) with an array.

Essentially you have to decide how you want to handle floating point operations. Do you want to store the extra precision and handle things in floating point (takes more computation time and memory, also you will have to convert back before saving your image or passing it to some other library since they usually deal only with integers) or do you want to just work with integers?

If you just want the integers then use:

```
np.array((np.clip(factor*(img - 128)+128,0,255), np.int8)
```

Comment: tried this `np.clip(factor*(img - 128)+128,0,255)` replacing loops but somehow result is not the same. The reason why i was implementing it from scratch because i wanted to understand more about  indepth working

Comment: @Hitesh, I think it has to do with numpy trying to be helpful by using floating point numbers, I've edited my answer with more details.